# How to Subtract value in filemaker?

Tags: database, filemaker

I have added a column and declared as calculation and the field name is subtrac. It has to be the value of (total cost - vendor paid). I have a column called vendor status(Paid/Unpaid). If the vendor paid status is "Unpaid" then only the calculation should take place.Else it should return 0. how to write the code? Please help me out.I'm new to it.

Comment: Use the If() function? http://www.filemaker.com/13help/en/html/func_ref3.33.12.html#1047177

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your post it really helps. If(State =”CA”;Subtotal * CA Tax Rate;0) i think this example will suits my case. can i write like this. If(vendor status=”Unpaid”;total cost - vendor paid;0) Correct? Please make the corrections if i'm wrong.

Comment: Sounds like it will do what you said you want it to do; why don't you try it and see for yourself. This is *really* basic stuff - not SO material, IMHO.

Comment: I'm new to it michael that's why i . is there any way to increment text field using button in filemaker? can you please suggest some way for that. It would be so helpful for me if you can give me the url also

Comment: Please ask a separate question about this. Make sure you also explain **why** you need it (it's a rather unusual request).

Comment: yes michael. i have created another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22166899/how-to-increment-the-text-field-in-filemaker-using-button

Answer (score 1):

The calculation in the comments on the original question is correct. I'm only placing it here so that the solution is in an answer rather than comments.

```
If(
    vendor status = "Unpaid";
    total cost - vendor paid;
    0
)
```